# resize icon without moving other elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, semantic-ui

I am using a jquery animation to resize an icon on hover. is there a way to have just the icon resize without having the other elements move?   run snippet below hover over the icon.   (here is the effect I am going for https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html hover over any of the icons)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.icon').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ fontSize : '3em' });
    }, function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({ fontSize : '1.5em' });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="ui doubling five column grid">
        <div class="column">     
          <div class="ui center aligned segment basic">
             <i class="large home icon"></i>
             <p style="padding-top: 5px;">
             home
             </p>       
          </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
    
    some other content
```

Comment: You could use `position: absolute` on the icon to take it out of the document flow, but I don't even see how it would work in terms of the UI, as it would cover the word 'home' if it didn't move down. Also note that you don't need any JS here. You can use CSS alone with the `:hover` selector and `transition` rule

Comment: You can try set .doubling > .column >.ui {minimum-height: [THIS_BLOCK_HEIGHT_ON_HOVER]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a transform and a transition instead. All CSS, no JS/JQ required

```css
.icon {
  transition:transform .25s ease;
}

.icon:hover {
  transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="ui doubling five column grid">
        <div class="column">     
          <div class="ui center aligned segment basic">
             <i class="large home icon"></i>
             <p style="padding-top: 5px;">
             home
             </p>       
          </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
    
    some other content
```